# Simple way to store NSMutableAttributedString in CoreData

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm trying to store an `NSMutableAttributedString` in `CoreData`, but am running into problems since some of the attributes of my `NSMutableAttributedString` contain Core Foundation objects that can't be archived. Is there an easy way to get this object to store in CoreData without having to do some messy stuff manually?

Comment: How would you propose storing stuff that can't be archived?

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald - That's what I'm asking, guess it's not possible?

Comment: What are the specific things that you have included in the properties? Can't you subclass them and add archiving to your own subclass.

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald - It's Core Foundation stuff like CGColorRef, CTFontRef, CTParagraphStyleRef. What I'm finding is I have to make my own subclass and convert all these values to UIKit. Guess there really isn't an easy way.

Comment: Mmm  and you can't get away with using standard attributes to achieve the same thing?

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald - Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Well I am not sure what you are trying to do with the attributed string, but if it's formatted text then can't you use NSFont, etc..  Take a look here http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/, I posted some stuff on formatting styles and images with uitextview and nstextview, but mostly it's about attributed strings. This stuff is all stored in core data.

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald - Yeah that does work, thanks! The problem was when I started using the NSAttributedString and CoreText, it was back when iOS5 was out, so I had to use the Core Foundation values, but now since iOS6 can use the NSForegroundColorAttributeName, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, NSFontAttributeName etc and those are accompanied by objects that can be archived. Anyway, thanks for helping me realize this, do you want to write it as an answer?

Comment: Sure it might help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started using `CoreText` when iOS5 was out, and thus used the Core Foundation values as attributes. However I now realize that since iOS6 came out, I can now use `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`, `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName`, `NSFontAttributeName`, etc. in the attributes dictionary, and those keys are accompanied by objects like `UIColor`, `NSMutableParagraphStyle`, and `UIFont` which can be archived.

Answer (score 5):

`NSMutableAttributedString` conforms to `NSCoding`, which means that it knows how to convert itself to/from an `NSData` and does so via a protocol that Core Data knows how to use.

Make the attribute "transformable", and then just assign attributed strings to it. Since it's transformable, Core Data will use `NSCoding` to convert it to `NSData` when you assign a value, and to convert it back to an attributed string when you read it.

Note, you won't be able to use a predicate to filter results on this field. But storing and retrieving it is simple.

Comment: It does conform to NSCoding, but it's possible that its properties won't (the attributes).

Answer (score 5):

While the above answer is right, it has one big disadvantage:

It is not possible to build a fetch request / predicate that queries the content of the NSAttributedString object!

A predicate like this will cause an exception when executed:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(content CONTAINS[cd] %@)", @"test"]];
```

To store an 'fetchable' NSAttributedString in Core Data is is needed to spilt the NSAttributedString into two parts: A NSString side (which can be fetched) and a NSData side, which stores the attributes.

This split can be achieved by creating three attributes in the Core Data entity:

1. a shadow NSString attribute ('contentString')
2. a shadow NSData attribute ('contentAttributes')
3. an 'undefined' transient attributed ('content')

In the custom entities class the 'content' attributed the created from its shadows and changes to the attribute are also mirrored to its shadows.

Header file:

```
/**
 MMTopic
*/
@interface MMTopic : _MMTopic {}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSAttributedString*   content;

@end
```

Implementation file:

```
/**
MMTopic (PrimitiveAccessors)

*/

@interface MMTopic (PrimitiveAccessors)

- (NSAttributedString *)primitiveContent;
- (void)setPrimitiveContent:(NSAttributedString *)pContent;

@end


/**
 MMTopic

 */
@implementation MMTopic    

static NSString const*  kAttributesDictionaryKey =  @"AttributesDictionary";
static NSString const*  kAttributesRangeKey =       @"AttributesRange";

/*
 awakeFromFetch

 */
- (void)awakeFromFetch {

    [super awakeFromFetch];

    // Build 'content' from its shadows 'contentString' and 'contentAttributes'
    NSString*                   string = self.contentString;
    NSMutableAttributedString*  content = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];

    NSData*                     attributesData = self.contentAttributes;
    NSArray*                    attributesArray = nil;
    if (attributesData) {
        NSKeyedUnarchiver*  decoder = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:attributesData];
        attributesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithCoder:decoder];
    }

    if ((content) &&
        (attributesArray.count)) {

        for (NSDictionary* attributesDictionary in attributesArray) {
            //NSLog(@"%@: %@", NSStringFromRange(((NSValue*)attributesDictionary[kAttributesRangeKey]).rangeValue), attributesDictionary[kAttributesDictionaryKey]);
            [content addAttributes:attributesDictionary[kAttributesDictionaryKey]
                             range:((NSValue*)attributesDictionary[kAttributesRangeKey]).rangeValue];
        }

        [self setPrimitiveContent:content];
    }
}

/*
 content

 */
@dynamic content;

/*
 content (getter)

 */
- (NSAttributedString *)content {

    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"content"];
    NSAttributedString* content = [self primitiveContent];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"content"];

    return content;
}

/*
 content (setter)

 */
- (void)setContent:(NSAttributedString *)pContent {

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"content"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:pContent forKey:@"content"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"content"];

    // Update the shadows
    // contentString
    [self setValue:pContent.string
            forKey:@"contentString"];

    // contentAttributes
    NSMutableData*      data = [NSMutableData data];
    NSKeyedArchiver*    coder = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    NSMutableArray*     attributesArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [pContent enumerateAttributesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, pContent.length)
                                 options:0
                              usingBlock:^(NSDictionary* pAttributesDictionary, NSRange pRange, BOOL* prStop) {
                                  //NSLog(@"%@: %@", NSStringFromRange(pRange), pAttributesDictionary);
                                  [attributesArray addObject:@{
                                                               kAttributesDictionaryKey:    pAttributesDictionary,
                                                               kAttributesRangeKey:     [NSValue valueWithRange:pRange],
                                                               }];
                              }];
    [attributesArray encodeWithCoder:coder];
    [coder finishEncoding];

    [self setValue:data
            forKey:@"contentAttributes"];
}

@end
```

Fetching can now be done by:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(contentString CONTAINS[cd] %@)", @"test"]];
```

While any access to the NSAttributedString goes like this:

```
textField.attributedText = pTopic.content;
```

The rules for working with 'Non-Standard attributes' in Core Data are documented here: [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001919-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

Well I am not sure what you are trying to do with the attributed string, but if it's formatted text then can't you use NSFont, etc..

Take a look here http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development, I posted some stuff on formatting styles and images with uitextview and nstextview, but mostly it's about attributed strings.

This stuff is all stored in core data.