# Core Data: How can I use NSPredicate on Transformable?

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

I want to perform a filtering on a `Transformable` attribute on Core Data. The `Transformer` value is actually an `NSAttributedString`. I tried to set a predicate like below:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(attributedString CONTAINS[cd] %@), _searchString];
```

**It did not work.** It certainly works with a `String` attribute.

I've googled it for a whole day, yet no luck. **Can someone tell me how to achieve that?** Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Transformer` in `CoreData`, but how do you saved the `NSAttributedString` into CoreData? You may need to do the "reverse" to filtrate on it `somethingAsAttributedString.string CONTAINS[c]...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple way to store NSMutableAttributedString in CoreData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648398/simple-way-to-store-nsmutableattributedstring-in-coredata)

Answer (score 4):

> I want to perform a filtering on a `Transformer` attribute on Core Data.

If you mean a Core Data "transformable" attribute, you really can't do that. Transformed attributes are simply a collection of bytes when they're stored in Core Data. It's not an attributed string in the persistent store-- it's just ones and zeroes. As a result you can't filter based on the attributed string contents.

Strings work because Core Data saves them as strings. But transformable attributes don't work that way. The only predicate you can use with this attribute is one that checks for nil or non-nil values.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I'm saving rich text content to Core Data as `Transformable` attribute, I want to filter rich text content by key words entered by users. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Not with a transformable, no.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, one thing you can do is denormalize your data a little and add the string value of your attributed string as an additional attribute, which you can then use to filter.

Comment: Or save the attributes as data separately from the string, then put them together when you want to present, if storage is an issue.